# ordenar lista con variable externa

Tags: java, programación-funcional, comparaciones

me gustaría saber si hay una manera mas funcional de lograr ordenar una lista, usando sort() o stream().sorted() pero entregando un parámetro externo.

Dejo aqui un ejemplo de como lo estoy haciendo de manera declarativa:

```
public List<prueba> ordenarLista(List<prueba> lista,String nombre){
List<prueba> orden = new ArrayList<>();
List<prueba> desorden = new ArrayList<>();
        
   lista.forEach(x->{
      if(x.getNombre().equals(nombre)){
                orden.add(x);
            }else{
                desorden.add(x);
            }
        });

        orden.addAll(desorden);
        return orden;
}
```

He realizado un par de pruebas como la siguiente:

```
return lista.stream()
.sorted((x,x2)-> x.getNombre().compareTo(nombre))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

pero no he logrado que funcione.

digamos que le entrego como nombre 'Juan', la idea es que salgan todos los 'Juan' primero.

Answer (score 0):

El sort ordena tanto ascendente como descendente por lo tanto, si quieres utilizarlo debes saber que le dará un orden alfabético si usas String, de todas formas te dejare el código que creo que intentas implementar, pero primero reduciré tu código si es eso lo que también necesitas, puedes hacer esto y te ahorraras instanciar una lista:

```
List<prueba> orden = new ArrayList<>();
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
        lista.forEach(x -> {
            if (x.getNombre().equals(nombre)) {
                orden.add(index.getAndIncrement(),x);
            }else {orden.add(x);}
        });
```

Esto te dejara en primer lugar al nombre que le pases como argumento.

Ahora si quieres ordenar alfabéticamente puedes hacer esto:

```
lista.sort((a, b) -> a.getNombre().compareTo(b.getNombre()));
```

Esto solo garantiza que 'Juan', por ejemplo, este en los primeros lugares solo si hay nombres cuyo orden alfabético sea posterior a 'Juan'

Comment: perfecto, me a quedado clarísimo, el primer ejemplo es justo lo que buscaba. Aun así pensé que con sort o sorted se podría hacer una solución similar, de todos modos muchas gracias.